# Why ~/USERNAME/bin/some_custom_command does not work as expected?

Tags: shell, fedora, path

I read *"Linux Bible 10th Edition"*, chapter 3: Using the shell, at 70 page. There is Tip section:

> If you want to add your own commands or shell scripts, place them in the bin directory in your home directory
> (such as /home/cn/bin for the user named cn). This directory is automatically added to your path in some Linux
> systems, although you may need to create that directory or add it to your PATH on other Linux systems. So, as long
> as you add the command to your bin with execute permission, you can begin using it by simply typing the command
> name at your shell prompt. To make commands available to all users, add them to **/usr/local/bin**

I'm running Fedora Linux 35 Workstation Edition and trying to create my custom command.
I've created **~/bin/kek.sh**

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo "Kek"
```

and go to the command line, enter `kek` in my home directory. I got `bash: kek: command not found...`. After that I went to my **~/.bashrc** and added following lines at the end of file

```
PATH=$PATH:~/home/bin/kek; export PATH;
```

Then returned to **~** directory, entered `kek` and got the same `bash: kek: command not found...`.
I've changed **.bashrc** PATH line to `PATH=$PATH:~/home/bin; export PATH;`, reload terminal session and always getting the same result.

Please, explain, why it didn't work for me? How can I create my own command and make it accessible just by it's name? Thank you.

Comment: `~` refers to your home directory. To add your `bin` subdirectory to the path you should use `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: You created an executable file named `kek.sh`, however you are invoking `kek`, in UX style OS's, files are identified by its magic number not by extension, so if you want to call that file there are three steps involved.
1.- Ensure that your PATH environment variable includes the PATH where your executable is located.

2.- Check that your file is executable, at least for the person that is executing (700 ~ rwx------, here read write execute for the owner)

3.- Invoke it with the name that was saved in the filesystem (respect upper and lower case).

that surely will do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PATH` variable indicates to your shell where executables may exist. So if you are placing your script `kek.sh` under `~/bin`, then you would want to add `~/bin` to `PATH`. However it appears that you have added `~/home/bin/kek` to your `PATH` instead.

Another problem is that the script is named `kek.sh`, however the command you are trying to execute is `kek`. Either you need to change the name of `kek.sh` to `kek` or you need to be running `kek.sh` as your command.

Putting `#!/usr/bin/bash` at the top of your script (known as a shebang) indicates to the system what interpreter should be used on the script. Naming it with a .sh at the end does not affect how the shell executes the script as far as I know, so simply naming it `kek` would not change how it is executed so long as the proper interpreter is in place after `#!`

Comment: So, it's the right way to append the whole `~/bin` directory to `$PATH` and not specific command?

Comment: Yes, you want to append the directory in which the commands you would like to execute exist and make sure that they have the execute bit set. You can `echo $PATH` to see how other directories have been set to see an example.